# Why does this jQuery pulls only three posts if I call the thumbnail image using JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating posts page for an app.
I am using JSON API and jQuery for this.

It pulls all the posts if I do not call the thumbnail image but it pulls/shows only three posts if I call the thumbnail.
I am so confused about this.

HTML markup :

```
<div class="page_single layout_fullwidth_padding">
    <div class="posts">

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery/Ajax:

```
myApp.onPageInit('blog', function (page) {

        var rootURL = 'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                  $('.posts').append('<div class="post_entry"><div class="post_thumb"><a href="blog-single.html"><img width="100%" src="'+value.better_featured_image.source_url+'" alt="" title="" /></a><div class="post_thumb_details"><a href="#" class="open-popup" data-popup=".popup-social"><img  src="images/icons/white/love.png" alt="" title="" /></a></div></div><div class="post_details">' +
                    '<h2><a href="blog-single.html">'+value.title.rendered+'</a></h2>' +
                    '<p>'+value.excerpt.rendered+'</p></div></div>');
                    ;
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }

        });

})
```

And I am getting following errors in the console tab:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source_url' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (my-app.js:97)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (my-app.js:96)
    at i (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
```

Why this can pull `source_url` for first three posts and can not for other posts? seems so weird.

if I chage this line

```
<img width="100%" src="'+value.better_featured_image.source_url+'" alt="" title="" />
```

to this / use a hardcoded image source like this

```
<img width="100%" src="http://www.example.com/images/01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

It shows all the posts.

This is a section/part of my example json response

```
{  
   "id":2304,
   "date":"2017-02-04T13:27:53",
   "date_gmt":"2017-02-04T07:57:53",
   "guid":{  
      "rendered":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/?p=2304"
   },
   "modified":"2017-02-05T15:11:38",
   "modified_gmt":"2017-02-05T09:41:38",
   "slug":"wann-ist-die-beste-zeit-um-arugam-bay-zu-besuchen-wetter-saisonen",
   "type":"post",
   "link":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wann-ist-die-beste-zeit-um-arugam-bay-zu-besuchen-wetter-saisonen\/",
   "title":{  
      "rendered":"Wann ist die beste Zeit um Arugam Bay zu besuchen? &#8211; Arugam Bay Wetter &#038; Saisonen \u2013"
   },

   "better_featured_image":{  
      "id":2268,
      "alt_text":"When to visit Arugam bay - Surfing in Arugam bay",
      "caption":"",
      "description":"",
      "media_type":"image",
      "media_details":{  
         "width":1600,
         "height":1200,
         "file":"2017\/02\/IRqSZt.jpg",
         "sizes":{  
            "thumbnail":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-150x150.jpg",
               "width":150,
               "height":150,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-150x150.jpg"
            },
            "medium":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-300x225.jpg",
               "width":300,
               "height":225,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-300x225.jpg"
            },
            "medium_large":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-768x576.jpg",
               "width":768,
               "height":576,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-768x576.jpg"
            },
            "large":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-1024x768.jpg",
               "width":1024,
               "height":768,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-1024x768.jpg"
            },
            "tiny-lazy":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-30x23.jpg",
               "width":30,
               "height":23,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-30x23.jpg"
            },
            "shop_thumbnail":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-180x180.jpg",
               "width":180,
               "height":180,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-180x180.jpg"
            },
            "shop_catalog":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-300x300.jpg",
               "width":300,
               "height":300,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-300x300.jpg"
            },
            "shop_single":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-600x600.jpg",
               "width":600,
               "height":600,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-600x600.jpg"
            },
            "post-thumbnail":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-249x187.jpg",
               "width":249,
               "height":187,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-249x187.jpg"
            },
            "full-width-image":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-1170x878.jpg",
               "width":1170,
               "height":878,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-1170x878.jpg"
            },
            "lp_bi_image":{  
               "file":"IRqSZt-750x350.jpg",
               "width":750,
               "height":350,
               "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt-750x350.jpg"
            }
         },
         "image_meta":{  
            "aperture":"0",
            "credit":"",
            "camera":"",
            "caption":"",
            "created_timestamp":"0",
            "copyright":"",
            "focal_length":"0",
            "iso":"0",
            "shutter_speed":"0",
            "title":"",
            "orientation":"0",
            "keywords":[  

            ],
            "resized_images":[  
               "370x200",
               "54x54",
               "460x260",
               "370x240"
            ]
         }
      },
      "post":2267,
      "source_url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/2017\/02\/IRqSZt.jpg"
   },
   "_links":{  
      "self":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2304"
         }
      ],
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
         }
      ],
      "about":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"
         }
      ],
      "author":[  
         {  
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/22"
         }
      ],
      "replies":[  
         {  
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=2304"
         }
      ],
      "version-history":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2304\/revisions"
         }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia":[  
         {  
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/2268"
         }
      ],
      "wp:attachment":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=2304"
         }
      ],
      "wp:term":[  
         {  
            "taxonomy":"category",
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=2304"
         },
         {  
            "taxonomy":"post_tag",
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=2304"
         }
      ],
      "curies":[  
         {  
            "name":"wp",
            "href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
            "templated":true
         }
      ]
   }
},
```

Comment: what error do you get when you don't change to hardcoded image src?

Comment: @Jai I've updated the question with consol error

Comment: Okay! It seems some of your json object does not have the `source_url` property. so code breaks there.

Comment: is something different with the forth json entry? somehow it seems that the forth entry is `null` and therefor it cant evaluate the source_url...

Comment: oh.. yeah.. thanks guys.. 4th post missed `featured image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the console error, there is something breaks after the 3rd post (thanks to @Jai) and it becomes NULL value the (thanks to @Merc)

So basically all the posts should have all the values/objects what we requires from the JSON.

What my fourth post missed was it's featured images..
as per my code all the posts should have a featured image and excerpt to display by the jQuery using JSON.

It was fixed by just adding the featured image to the 4th post.